# How do I choose the first tuple within a list and save the rest of the tuples in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I want be able to input the following:

```
fun([{X,Y}, {A,B}, {M,N}]).
```

and only use the first tuple and save the others for later use. I tried defining it like this:

```
fun([{X|Y}, V]) ->
V.
```

But I just get a syntax error before the "|". "V" was just to try and output to see what was happening.

Is there any resources I can be pointed towards for some support with this? Or am I doing something really wrong?

Comment: You also asked for resources: try LearnYouSomeErlang.com (Lists section: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func([{X,Y}| V]) -> %% fun is a keyword, you cannot use it as a function name
   %% do some stuff with X, Y
   V.
```

generally, if you want to apply the same function to all element of a list, it is good to use the lists module: (lists:foreach/2, lists:map/2, lists:foldl/2 ...) or a list comprehension

```
Res = [Fun(T) || T <- L]
```

wher Fun is the function to apply to each tuple T from the list L

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this:
`fun([{X, Y} | V])`.

`[{X, Y} | V] = [{X,Y}, {A,B}, {M,N}]`, then `V = [{A,B}, {M,N}]`